# How to bind database from C# code to my xaml file in MVVM sung livechart pie chart? I can't hardcode it, if I add a new project. It should reflect it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

```
                <lvc:PieChart LegendLocation="Bottom" DataClick="Chart_OnDataClick" Hoverable="False" DataTooltip="{x:Null}">
                    <lvc:PieChart.Series>
                        <lvc:PieSeries Title="Project 1" Values="3" DataLabels="True"
                           LabelPoint="{Binding PointLabel}"/>
                        <lvc:PieSeries Title="Project 2" Values="4" DataLabels="True" 
                           LabelPoint="{Binding PointLabel}"/>
                        <lvc:PieSeries Title="Project 3" Values="6" DataLabels="True" 
                           LabelPoint="{Binding PointLabel}"/>
                        <lvc:PieSeries Title="Project 4" Values="2" DataLabels="True" 
                           LabelPoint="{Binding PointLabel}"/>
                    </lvc:PieChart.Series>
                </lvc:PieChart>
```

I do not want to hardcode it like this. It should see what project exists in my database and reflect it. Not sure how to bind it.

[image]

So if I my databse is updated to have 10 projects. It should reflect it here regardless of the value, as of now. I am just trying to get the projects to be reflected on the pie chart.

Comment: That bit of XAML is essentially `new PieChart()`. It's simply using a declaritive way to define those objects. You can totally instantiate them somewhere else, then add it into the control tree.

Comment: You may also be able to bind that top-level `PieChart.Series` to something in your model of the same type, and manipulate your list of things in code. I don't know your libraries though.

Comment: By any chance, could you please show me an example? I have no idea how to proceed on.